# Axis 2 web service call returns soap fault 1 with indexoutofbounds exception

Tags: java, soap, apache-axis

Hello everyone I have the following:

```
public ChampionResponseWrapper getChampions(@WebParam(name="cityStateId")   
Integer[] cityStateIds){
......
.......
}
```

The above method is within an Axis2 web service and I am using hibernate to retrieve data from the database although this seems irrelevant for the issue I am encountering.

I am using soapui to generate a request for testing purposes but instead of a response I am getting a fault error

Upon looking into the logs I see the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.ArrayINdexOutOfBoundsException: 1
   at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.deserialize(BeanUtil.java:639)
........
........
```

Upon attaching a debugger to the method and sending the request again I don't even get as far as the method which tells me this is something to do with Axis2 but I am none the wiser after a google fu attempt.

Any enlightenment on the issue would be awesome.

Comment: Is this running in a servlet container like Tomcat or something else? If so, what?

Comment: hi this is running on tomcat